# How to install supertuxkart without console or ubuntu software?

Tags: software-installation, games, 21.10

i want to install lastest supertuxkart (1.3), but when i install it from ubuntu software or terminal i get supertuxkart 1.2. I need help on how to install it from supertuxkart website and show the app in "show applications" menu. Also i have ubuntu 21.10.

Answer (score 2):

Version 1.3 is available as a snap:

```
~$ snap find supertuxkart
Name          Version  Publisher   Notes  Summary
supertuxkart  1.3      diddledani  -      A 3D arcade racer with a variety of characters, tracks, and modes to play
```

You can install it with the terminal command

```
snap install supertuxkart
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the [official ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Estk/+archive/ubuntu/dev)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stk/dev
sudo apt-get update
```

Install the program

```
sudo apt install supertuxkart
```

Resulting version

```
$ apt policy supertuxkart
supertuxkart:
  Installed: 1.3+build2~ubuntu20.04.1
```

Answer (score 0):

The official PPA is preferred as [Organic Marble](https://askubuntu.com/users/243321/organic-marble) answered. Though without console, you may grab the packages directly from PPA packages page:

[https://launchpad.net/~stk/+archive/ubuntu/dev/+packages](https://launchpad.net/%7Estk/+archive/ubuntu/dev/+packages)

In that page, scroll down and click expand the source for Ubuntu 21.10, then grab the packages below for your PC:

```
supertuxkart-data_1.3+build2~ubuntu21.10.1_all.deb
supertuxkart_1.3+build2~ubuntu21.10.1_amd64.deb
```

There are also `arm64` and `ppc64el` architecture packages for Ubuntu running  on Raspberry Pi or other devices.

Finally double-click (or right-click and select open with Software Install) to install the `supertuxkart-data` package first since it's a dependency package, and then `supertuxkart`.